# Reference Request: Carnot Group Not Containing Group of Isometries

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

This question is a follow-up to [this post,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1592257/35400)  from which I quote:

> Let $\mathfrak{e}$ be the 3-dimensional Lie algebra with basis $(H,X,Y)$ and bracket $[H,X]=Y$, $[H,Y]=-X$, $[X,Y]=0$. It is isomorphic to the Lie algebra of the group of isometries of the plane. Its central extension $\tilde{\mathfrak{e}}$ is defined as the 4-dimensional Lie algebra defined by adding a central generator $Z$ and the additional nonzero bracket $[X,Y]=Z$.

It seems to me that since $\mathrm{exp}$ is a diffeomorphism on a Carnot group then the latter's Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, should not contain either $\mathfrak{e}$ or $\tilde{\mathfrak{e}}$.  However, where can I find a proof of the fact that no Carnot group contains either $\mathfrak{e}$ or $\tilde{\mathfrak{e}}$ (without going through the Sato-Dixmier result of the quoted post).

Comment: It's immediate that $\mathfrak{e}$ (and hence $\tilde{\mathfrak{e}}$) is not nilpotent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lie algebra of a Carnot group is nilpotent.  But a nilpotent Lie algebra cannot contain nonzero elements $H,X,Y$ satisfying $[H,X]=Y$ and $[H,Y]=-X$, for then arbitrarily long brackets of the form
$$[H, [H, [H, \dots,[H,X]\dots]]]$$
would equal something nonzero (either $\pm X$ or $\pm Y$).  This rules out the possibility of containing either $\mathfrak{e}$ or $\tilde{\mathfrak{e}}$.

Comment: Oh, I feel silly now.  Thank Nate.